# Get cities within radius from a location (Google Map API)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

I'm doing a little project which heavily relies on locations and my question here is...

Is it possible to use the google map API to get cities within a certain radius from a location so that I can reduce the number of times I have to query on my database before I get the results I want?

I have previously done a radius search by using the locations stored on my database and I'm thinking that if it is not possible to get the cities within radius with just the use of the google map API,

My alternative solution would be to get all locations (stored in my database) within a certain radius by filtering them via lat and lng and get all distinct localities of the returned locations.

However, results can be inaccurate. Because there can be datas stored up in my database that might not show up if it is not within radius from the location specified during radius search, despite being in the same city/locality, which is actually the filter that I want.

Comment: I do not know if it is possible to use the google api to get cities within a certain region.  I have a database that contains the US city, state, zipcodes,  with lat & longs for the center of the zipcode. I use the haversine formula to return all rows within the radius.